# Почему с пользователем SYSTEM ошибка: SP2-0382: The SHOW PDBS command is not available?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle18c

Пытаюсь создать пользователей в Oracle XE 18.4 при использовании [официального образа docker](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0).

[Этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33331148/34088) предлагает выполнить команду `SHOW PDBS`, но когда подключаюсь как пользователь `SYSTEM`, выполнение этой команды недоступно:

```
SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT

SQL> show pdbs
SP2-0382: The SHOW PDBS command is not available
```

Хотя `help show` показывает эту опцию как действительную. Не могу войти как `SYS` или `PDBADMIN`.

Пытался сбросить пароли командой: `bash /opt/oracle/setPassword.sh new_password`, но это не помогло.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы запустить `show pdbs`?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Which user can execute SHOW PDBS on Oracle 18.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62411032) от участника [@Aaron Digulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62411032

Answer (score 3):

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SHOW.html#GUID-6BB1499D-E537-43D1-A209-401F5DB95E16) утверждается, что команда `SHOW PDBS` работает для любого пользователя с DBA привилегиями.

Oднако в документе поддержки:

> SP2-0382: The SHOW PDBS Command Is Not Available (Doc ID 2669189.1)

сказано, что в SQL*Plus была выявлена ошибка, и только `SYSDBA` может использовать эту команду.

В качестве обходного пути, можно запросом получить те же данные с представлением `V$PDBS`, хотя результат будет не так хорошо отформатирован:

```
select con_id, name, open_mode, restricted from v$pdbs;
```

---

*Прим.ред.*: в 19.3 ошибка пока не исправлена.

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422062) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>